# On mouse hover, display the corresponding sizes of bars, as mentioned in the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function draw() {
  var nums = document.getElementById("number").value.split(",");
  console.log(nums);
  var w = 40;
  var factor = 20;
  var n_max = Math.max.apply(parseInt, nums);
  var h_max = factor * n_max;
  console.log("h max is " + h_max);
  console.log("n max is " + n_max);
  //var h_max = Math.max(h);
  //var a = parseInt(nums);
  //var create = document.getElementById("shape");
  for (var i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
    //var x = parseInt(nums[i]);

    //var final_width = w / x;
    var x_cor = (i + 1) * w;
    //var y_cor = i * w * 0.5;
    var h = factor * nums[i];
    console.log(x_cor);
    console.log(h);
    //console.log(h_max);   



    var change = document.getElementById("histContainer");
    //change.className = 'myClass';
    var bar = document.createElement("div");
    bar.className = 'myClass';
    //var c_change = document.createElement("div2");
    //change.appendChild(c_change);
    change.appendChild(bar);

    console.log(change);
    //change.style.x.value = x_cor;
    //change.style.y.value = y_cor;
    bar.style.position = "absolute";
    bar.style.top = (h_max - h) + "px";
    //bar.style.transform = "rotate(-1deg)"
    bar.style.left = i * w * 1 + "px";
    bar.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(1,211,97)";
    bar.style.opacity = "0.6";
    bar.style.width = w + "px";
    bar.style.height = h + "px";

    //var color1 = document.getElementById("histContainer");
    //var bar_color = document.createElement("div");
    //color1.appendChild(change);
    //bar.style.color = "rgba(1,211,97,0.6)";
  }
}

function color() {
  //draw();  
  var change1 = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');

  for (var i = 0; i < change1.length; i++) {
    change1[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,0,27)";
    console.log("Change1 = " + change1[i]);
  }



  // var bar1 = document.createElement("div2");
  // change1.appendChild(bar1);
  // console.log(change1);
  //change1.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(1,,254,16)";


}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("mouseover", ".myClass", function() {

    //var number = this.nums;
    //$(this.nums).text($(this.nums).index());
    //$(".myClass").append(nums);
    var shade = $(this).css("opacity");
    $(this).css("opacity", "1.0");

    $(document).on("mouseout", ".myClass", function() {

      $(this).css("opacity", shade);


    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Number:<input type="text" id="number" /><br>
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="Draw" onClick="draw()" /><br>
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="Change Color" onClick="color()" /><br>
  <div id="histContainer" style="position: relative;"> </div>
  <!-- <label for="mouseover" id="label1">Bar Value</label><br>
     <input type="text" name="mouseover" id="text2" value="0"/><br> -->
  <!-- <input type="button" id="color_change" style="float: right;" value="Change Color" /> -->
```

My Question is- I have entered some numbers as Input, and corresponding histogram is made according to the input values. Now, I have created mouseover() on each bar, and WANT to display their proportionate sizes, as given in input.
Can you provide me some help? Only thing which i figured out was- I have to call my draw function in the jQuery mouseover.
REFER TO the draw() and jQuery function(last)

Comment: Why $(document).on("mouseout", inside of $(document).on("mouseover" block?

Comment: Because, once I hover out, the histogram reverts back to normal shades only.

Comment: do you want to have the numbers show up on the bars themselves ? or are looking for something more like a "tooltip" ?

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer. It is required that the nums array has to be re-declared again.

**Solution Achieved**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on("mouseover",".myClass", function(){

            //var numbers = $("#number").serialize();
            //var number = this.nums;
            var nums = document.getElementById("number").value.split(",");
            $(this).text(nums[$(this).index()]);
            //$(".myClass").append(nums);
            var shade = $(this).css("opacity");
            $(this).css("opacity", "1.0");

             $(document).on("mouseout",".myClass", function() {

               $(this).css("opacity", shade);


             });

        }); 
    });
```